# GXT tree highlight nodes

Tags: tree, nodes, highlight, gxt

How can I highlight the tree nodes programmatically without selecting them?
Reason being I would want to have my tree read only (not allowing user to make selection) yet want to display the already selected nodes. Any ways to do it?
I'm using GXT 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first places I look when trying to get answers to GXT questions is the [GXT Guides](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/). There are 3 sections on that page which you will find helpful here, [Appearance Design](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/concepts/appearance/Appearance_3.html), [Tree Widgets](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/ui/tree/Tree.html), and possibly [Themes](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/ui/theme/Themes.html).

I think the best choice here will be creating your own custom `TreeAppearance`. I believe that the `TreeAppearance.renderNode(...)` method will be of most interest.

You could also create a custom `TreeView<M>` and override the `onTextChange(TreeNode<M>, SafeHtml)` method. If you look at the source for the `TreeView` class, you should get some ideas on how you can access and manipulate the html for any given node. Once you have access to the html element, you can simply apply a CSS class to achieve the effect you need.

Comment: 1. I tried `TreeAppearance.renderNode(...)` but it gave me an exception. Can't even load my tree. Seems like due to empty store while it is applying the appearance.

2. When is `onTextChange(TreeNode<M>, SafeHtml)` being called? I tried to println something from within but no output.

3. I tried `setCell(...)`, overriding `render(...)` with
`SafeHtml c = SafeHtmlUtils.fromString("<div " + "style='background-color:#E6E6FA'>" + g.getName() + "</div>");
sb.append(c);`

and the name of my nodes displayed with the html quotes